# Most efficient way to use downloaded background image between activities in Android?

Tags: android, image, performance, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com as backend for an app. The app downloads its background image from Parse by Parse's "pinning"-feature to the local datastore. I want to use the same background image for all activities. When loading the image it's kind of slow though, there is about 500-1000 ms of white background before the image loads. What's the most efficient way to load the image and use it in all activities? Should I load it once and then pass the bytes via extras, should I use something like Picasso, should I save the image in a different way or should I use Parse's own ParseImageView (which I am doing now)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Picasso for loading ParseFiles - it uses cache, so once loaded you don't need to reload it, and I think it's faster than using ParseImageFile. To get URL of the file you can use [`ParseFile.getUrl()`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html#getUrl()) method and pass this link to Picasso. Also you can call add `noFade` when creating Picasso request to disable image fading then loading it

Answer (score 0):

You can make your app as a single activity app. Now, you have to download the image only once,use fragments with transparent background for showing different screens. This will remove the delay of showing image in new activity,as we would replace one fragment with another. There would be delay only once while loading image in background for the activity.